# How to query a ActiveRecord Relation for created_by field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

So i'm currently using the following command to join and query my tables - looking for an **OrderItem** amongst my **Orders** where the **orderable_id** = **applicable_product_item_id** the **total_price** = 0 and the **buyer_id** = **current_user**

```
Order.joins(:items)
     .where(order_items: {id: OrderItem.where(orderable_id: applicable_product_item_id)})
     .where(total_price: 0)
     .where(buyer_id: current_user)
```

This all works fine, but now i want to query further and i want to know if the order that it has found has a **created_at** date > **searchable_created_by_date**

i've tried using another .where in the query as well as selecting the .first in the array and further querying that i.e. query = above_query.first

then

```
query.where("created_at > ?", searchable_created_by_date)
```

but i get

```
Undefined method where for #<Order:0x007fbc8d8edf90>
```

Comment: When you do `query = above_query.first`, you no longer have a chainable query. That's why you get the `no method error`. So, that's a no-go. What did you get when you simply tried to chain on an additional `.where` statement?

Comment: can you show where query getting initialized?

Comment: @jvillian when i chain the .where i get column reference "created_at" is ambiguous

Comment: You'll have to specify the table in your where clause -- `.where("orders.created_at > ?", searchable_created_by_date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

furman87's comment sounds right to me:

> You'll have to specify the table in your where clause -- .where("orders.created_at > ?", searchable_created_by_date)

You might also try:

```
Order.
  where(total_price: 0).
  where(buyer_id: current_user).
  where("created_at > ?", searchable_created_by_date).
  joins(:order_items).
  where(order_items: {id: OrderItem.where(orderable_id: applicable_product_item_id)})
```

I *think* putting the `created_at` statement before the `joins` statement will disambiguate the query - but I'm not 100% sure.

Also, I would have thought that you would have done `joins(:order_items)`. But, I suppose that depends on how you have your associations set up.  If `joins(:items)` works for you, then more power to you! (And ignore the comment.)

Comment: thanks guys - orders.created_at removed the ambiguity